# Changing a group header on Facebook with code

Tags: facebook, rotation, banner

This might be a wild goose chase, but decided to ask the experts anyway. I've heard that you can (partly) program Facebook Pages and Groups. I am associated with a FB Group where the Header image or banner is often replaced, on a rotation bases.

Is there a way in which one coud do this automatically through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik it´s only possible with App Groups, you can read about that in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group#update

About App Groups: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/game-groups